# is there a way to add keys to child clauses in jq

Tags: jq

I want to add a value to a json text, but `jq '.jq_path +{"key":"value"}'` will only output that section and `jq '. +{jq_path:{"key":"value"}}'` will replace all that is written within the section to which the path points (here described as jq_path).

Input

```json
{
"object":{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
},
"key3":"value3"
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
"object":{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2",
"key":"value"
},
"key3":"value3"
}
```

What I got with `jq '. +{"object":{"key":"value"}}'`

```json
{
"object":{
"key":"value"
},
"key3":"value3"
}
```

**I found the following workaround for me:**

```bash
function json_add_value(){
    input=$(</dev/stdin); jq_path=$1; jq_addition=$2
    
    jq_section=$(echo $input | jq "$jq_path +{$jq_addition}" | sed -e '1d' -e '$d')
    
    echo $input | jq "$jq_path ={$jq_section}"
}
```

```bash
# syntax
cat $json_file | json_add_value ".jq_path" '"key":"value"'
```

However, I would like to use a more official way (at best only using jq). How could I do that?

Comment: Can you [show us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/731498/edit) a working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the JSON you're starting with, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Give the path to the explicit key you want to add or change and assign its value.

   ```
   jq '.object.key = "value"' file
   ```
2. Use `+=` to "add to" the object at the path `.object`.  If the given key already exists in `.object`, its value will be updated to the new value.

   ```
   jq '.object += { "key": "value" }' file
   ```

The result in each case is the same:

```json
{
  "object": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key": "value"
  },
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

The issue in your first attempt (essentially `.object + { "key": "value" }`) is that you extract the object and then add to it. The result of that operation is the `.object` with the new key+value added to it and nothing else (you lose the other top-level keys).

The issue in your second attempt (essentially `. + { "object": { "key": "value" } }`) is that you add a new `object` key to the top-level object, overwriting the old value.